# Cannot setup CodeCommit in EB CLI

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

After terminating my previous environment in EB CLI with  `eb terminate` , which executed successfully, I have been trying to deploy my node app in a different region.  When I navigate to my app folder containing and hit `eb init`, I am prompted with

```
$ eb init
Cannot setup CodeCommit because there is no Source Control setup, continuing with initialization
```

What can I do from here?

I double checked in IAM and the user has full codecommit access

Comment: In my case this was happening because I had terminated all the environments for that particular application. When I created those environment, this error was gone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you have not initialized git in your directory. Try running `git init` in the directory you want to use with CodeCommit via the EB CLI.

If you have done this and it is still not working the environment you are using may not be accessible to git and may need to be installed.

Comment: I came across the same issue but in my case it was due to bad project structure as the `.git` folder is in a parent directory. It looks like EB CLI is looking for the version control folder, in my case `.git` in the pwd where you do `eb init`. As my project is already version controlled rather than `git init` in the pwd I only created a `.git` folder in the pwd.

Answer (score 5):

It happened to me.
I turned out that it happens because I already have a **`.elasticbeanstalk`** folder in this directory.
Which means there is already an elastic bean application configured.
And it will continue with the existing configurations.

### Solution:

**Delete** the **`.elasticbeanstalk`** directory.